# How to retrieve response from server using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am sending filename to server and trying to get some sort of response to make sure api calls are working but its always returing 404 even though path is correct, I am not sure where i am making mistake , Any idea ?

angularjsFactory.js

```
getFile:function(file_name){
            return $http.get("/file?file_name="+file_name);
        }
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
var readDirectory = require('./readDirectory');

app.get('/file', function(req, res) {
    var path = './ditLogs';
    var fileParam = req.query.file_name;
    console.log(fileParam);
    fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {
        items.forEach(function(items) {
            if (fileParam === items) {
                res.sendFile(items);
                console.log(items);
            }
        });
    });
});
app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
    //console.log('app is printing data',obj);
    //ditProducer.startProducer();
    setTimeout(function() {
        ditconsumer.start();
    }, 2000);

});
```

Comment: Did you try adding a forward slash '/' to the end of the url

Answer (score 1):

Your route on server is not correct comparing to the call from angular's side. You are not using route parameters, but query string.

Try this:

```
app.get('/file', function (req, res) {
    // get filename using: req.query.file_name
    res.send('FIle data');
 });
```

Or you can try this on angular and keep the server code:

```
 $http.get("/file/"+ encodeURI(file_name));
```

Comment: is there way to pass parameter as i am passing in question ?

Comment: i dont know filename is passing as /test.txt , i dont know why

Comment: @hussain: coz correct syntax will be: $http.get("/file?file_name="+file_name); if you change node js code to app.get('/file', function (req, res) {
    // get filename using: req.query.file_name
    res.send('FIle data');
 });

Answer (score 0):

Server side code looks incorrect.

```
app.get('/file', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.query.file_name);//This will give you filename passed as url param
    res.send('FIle data');
 });
```

Comment: i updated my server code to give you better understanding what i am trying to do

Comment: Can you confirm that you are not adding this middle-ware app.get('/file', function (req, res) {
    // get filename using: req.query.file_name
    res.send('FIle data');
 });  at the last in app.js

Comment: Its should be above: ` // catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
}); ` need to check your app.js

Comment: @hussain: all looks well to me dude..  Did you restart the node js server after making the changes? :D Sometime i missed out in early days.. Also just curious to know, what happens if you try hitting by browser?

Comment: problem is my if statement is not satisfying because fileParam value is /test.text that is not matching when if(fileParam === file) because file value is without forward / test.txt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116136/discussion-between-hussain-and-ritesh-nitw).